# Trying to optimize my Angular HttpClient call with credentials in the url

Tags: angularjs

I have to make calls with this format

`https://username:password@my.domain.com/api`

in ajax I did something like this

```
$.ajax({
          url: endPoint,
          type: 'POST',
          async: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          username: myUsername,
          password: myPassword,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
               xhr.withCredentials = true;
               xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
          }
    });
```

how can I do the same thing with the new Angular's HttpClient without doing something like this?

```
let url = baseProtocol + username + ":" + password + "@" + baseUrl

this.http.post(url,{
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  }
}).subscribe( res => {
    //do stuff
  }, err => {
    //do other bad related stuff
  }
```

it works but this string concatenation is ugly.
I'm not a specialist of this kind of technology, I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would do that but anyways.

What I would do is either make a function in a service, with several variables (user, domain, etc.).

When you call the function, it returns the full URL.

This would look like this :

```
user: string;
password: string;
domain: string;
endpoint: string;

get url() { return `https://${this.user}:${this.password}@${this.domain}/${this.endpoint}`; }
```

All you need to do is set your variable values, and in any http call, all you need to do is

```
let url = this.myService.url;
```

Comment: in my project it almost looked like that, my question is not about code design but about the HttpClient component and its ability to get clean urls and credentials

Comment: HttpClient is used to make http calls. For that, you need to give it an URL. So you need to build this URL. So I would say no. **But**, you could use an Interceptor, to rebuild your URL just before making your call. Is it what you asked ? Because otherwise, I have no idea how to help you ...

Comment: I posted the Ajax query just because of this, the real question is "am I doing all I can do for making a good call"? The Ajax approach was smoother

Comment: That's what you get with high level abstraction frameworks ! AJAX might be flexible, but Angular's HttpClient is simpler to use. So, is the Interceptor a good alternative for you ?

Comment: No, it adds logic where should not be logic. I should handle specific cases and I think it's not..the case :P